# SSL Error in Big Query using Simba ODBC Driver C#

Tags: ssl, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, simba

I am using Simba ODBC driver (32-bit) to query data from Google Big Query using C#. I keep getting the below error one or two times per week. Please help as I am not sure how to resolve this error.

> ERROR [HY000] [Simba][DriverSupport] (1160) Cannot enable SSL for the
>   connection when connecting to a server that has not enabled SSL. If
>   the server has SSL enabled, please check if it has been configured to
>   use a SSL protocol version that is lower than what is allowed for the
>   connection. The minimum SSL protocol version allowed for the
>   connection is: TLS 1.1.

Comment: hi can you provide some more info.. which product are you using..I would think it is some type of visualization software like PowerBI for example?

Comment: Hi Paddy, I used MS Visual Studio 2012 in C# code to connect to Google Cloud Big Query through Simba ODBC driver.